# BitLocker does not recognize USB drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, bitlocker

I can't get BitLocker to recognize a USB flash drive.
It previously had BitLocker enabled, it was removed via formatting and now I want to re-enable it.

Problem is the option no longer shows up in the right-click context menu.
Nor does the BitLocker management app seem to recognize it as a flash drive.

[image][image]

I formatted the drive a few times. Used NTFS and exFat to no avail.

Comment: Show the disk in Disk Mangement

Answer (score 4):

Using "Disk Management" I deleted the partition from the USB stick and then created a simple volume, using all the disk space, which was then Formatted (not a quick format ) with NTFS.

I removed the drive from the server (2019 Essentials) ensured the Bitlocker Drive Encryption Service was started ( Run > Services.msc).
Placed the drive back in the server and encryption was possible via the context (right click) menu. I think this is caused by the partition on the new USB drive being set to "active" and/or there being unused space on the USB stick.

Comment: Normal USB sticks don't have a partition table on them usually, just a file system, BitLocker needs a partition table, which is created by disk managment.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

After formatting the USB stick (NO quickformat!) the bitlocker option re-appeared inside the context menu (right click).

Answer (score 1):

Other answers here claims that destructive way of formatting drive is the only way to enable BitLocker for given removable drive. [I found this to be not true](https://onezeronull.com/2021/02/28/cant-enable-bitlocker-for-pendrive-or-usb-removable-drive/). In my case simple deactivation of primary (the only?) partition on pendrive did the trick and enabled BitLocker back.

Try following steps:

1. Click *Start*, type `cmd`, right-click *Command Prompt* and select *Run as administrator* from context menu.
2. Type `diskpart` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type `list disk` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Locate your removable drive by looking at *Size* column.
4. Type `select disk n` where `n` is number (in *Disk ###* column) that corresponds to your disk. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Type `list partition` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Usually your drive will have only one
6. Type `select partition 1` (or other number) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
7. Type `inactive` to make selected partition inactive and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
8. Type `exit` twice and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to leave *DiskPart* and *Command Prompt*.

The "*DiskPart marked the current partition as inactive*" should confirm success. ou should now be able to use BitLocker on your removable drive. Open BitBlocker to enable encryption of given removable disk.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: This didn't work for me on my USB drive. i get the error message "The disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The INACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks."