# USB bitlocker recovery key not working & Bitlocker doesn't detect USB key

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I have Bitlocker recovery keys saved to my USB drive. They unlock my SSD.

I know these are the correct keys, because the Identifier in the recovery key text file on the USB matches the Identifier that pops up in Bitlocker when I try to open my SSD:

[image]

But when I enter , it tells me "the key doesn't match this drive".

[image]

When I click "Load keys from USB drive", it tells me a valid USB key wasn't detected...even though I literally have the USB open in a separate window with the files!

I tried following [trejder's steps in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1216214/bitlocker-does-not-recognize-usb-drive) to deactivate any USB partitions that aren't in use, but command prompt tells me "The disk is not a fixed MBR disk. The INACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks."

What else can I do to make this recovery key work?

Edit - here is the output of `manage-bde protectors D: -get`

```
Volume D: [Label Unknown]
All Key Protectors

Password:
  ID: {952155BB-5663-4695-87A3-03CA5F37D687}

Numerical Password:
  ID: {5EE2EF79-59AF-4617-98E9-EDCFE9515FD7}

External Key:
  ID: {9C1C51E1-71B0-4141-A901-5AF08A3FEF6A}
  External Key File Name:
    9C1C51E1-71B0-4141-A901-5AF08A3FEF6A.BEK`
```

I tried entering the Numerical Password from here as well and it does not work.

Comment: Yep, copy/pasted the key, not the identifier.

Comment: I ran manage-bde as an admin and made progress - I tried entering both .bek files and it still says it failed to unlock. I tried the .txt files and it says "An error occured while attempting to read the key from disk." idk, maybe these keys are just straight up wrong, but I have no idea how - I just made them yesterday.

Comment: "What else can I do to make this recovery key work?" - The only way I know is to disable BitLocker then reenable BitLocker protection and save the new recovery key that is generated. "I tried following these steps to deactivate any USB partitions" - Which steps?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include a link to the steps. I just added them.

Comment: I am also confused because BitLocker asks me for both a password and a recovery key. Is the password the same as what I normally use to log in to my local account? Like upon startup?

Comment: @digitalwaterfall - The password would NOT be the username password.  You also have a numerical pin that can be used to unlock the volume.

Comment: Dang I have no memory of entering that. Is it the same password that comes from the output of " manage-bde protectors D: -get "? I put those results in the question just now.